# Relation between surjective and one-to-one functions.

Tags: functions

I could use some help again.
Let $f,g$ be functions from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$.
Also known is that $f(n) = g(2n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Assuming that $f$ is a surjective function, how do you prove that $g$ is not a one-to-one function?

Cheers

Comment: $g(1)$ must be equal to some $f(k)$. Therefore, $g(1)=g(2k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ be a positive odd integer. Then $g(m)\in\mathbb{N}$.

As $f$ is surjective, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=g(m)$.

But this implies that $g(m)=g(2n)$, with $m\ne 2n$.

So $g$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is a surjection, $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(k)=g(1)$.

$$g(2k)=g(1)$$.

Hence $g$ is not injective.